# Municipal Bonds and Taxes

Tags: united-states, taxes, income-tax, bonds, municipal-bonds

A certain investor buys a a Municipal bond for $10,000. He then collects $3000 of tax free interest from the bond and after some time sells the bond for $8000. Does he have a capital loss for tax purposes? and if so, how much?

Note: The investor lives in the United States and is a citizen of the United States.

Bob

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The investor has $2000 capital loss. The dividends were recognized as income already, and as such are not affecting the basis. They're just not taxed.

Comment: It's tax-free "Interest" income, not "dividend" income.

Comment: @michael same thing.

Comment: If you believe them to be the same thing, pls explain.

Comment: @michael it doesn't matter in this context. Depending on the type of the investment it is either dividends or interest, but it is entirely irrelevant.

Comment: @litleadv... got it... "context is everything"